# Criar novos "panel" de forma dinâmica com php e mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, panel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de hotel e quero representar cada apartamento cadastrado no sistema com um panel contendo informações, ou seja, na para cada apartamento o sistema gera um novo panel que é exibido para o usuário. Essa é a estrutura do panel

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">201(numero do quarto)
                    <span class="pull-right clickable panel-toggle"><em class="fa fa-toggle-up"></em></span></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>(Aqui vai o conteudo do panel)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Lembrando que em cada panel deve exibir o numero do apartamento e se ele está ou ou não ocupado. Espero que tenha dado para entender o que estou tentando fazer

Comment: Basta selecionar todos os registros do seu banco de dados, fazer um laço de repetição que percorra todos e, para cada um, gerar o código HTML desejado. Quer tentar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não entendi direito o que você está tentando fazer, mas caso você queira que o programa crie esses panels com o php, eu usaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
$array = array[$query];
$apartamentos = $array[0];
//$query seria o comando para selecionar os apartamentos, algo que poderia ter incrementeado

for($i=0;$i<$apartamentos;$i++)
echo ' <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">'.$apartamento[$i].'
                <span class="pull-right clickable panel-toggle"><em class="fa fa-toggle-up"></em></span></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>(Aqui vai o conteudo do panel)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
```

Comment: Aqui é só um exemplo de como fazer a repetição. Não entendi o resto porque não ficou bem claro.

Comment: Era basicamente isso mesmo, amigo. Obrigado, já deu pra pegar a lógica e seguir aqui!